# ErrorDocument in apache doesn't handle all cases

Tags: apache, redirect

mydomain.com/badurl.html redirects correctly to mydomain.com/en/404.html, but mydomain.com/en/badurl.html does not and goes to a blank page, literally. Looks like adding a locale 'en' throws it off, rest of the locales seem to work OK.

This is my Virtual Host

```
ErrorDocument 404 /en/404-error.html
```

P.S it is outside all directives but .

Answer (score 0):

You're probably sending those requests to something like PHP that sees them and returns something other than 404 to Apache.  There are cases where plugins can even send a 404, but tell Apache the response was successful.  Those do not trigger ErrorDocument.